# Diagonal argument applied to computable numbers

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals, computability, turing-machines

Upon applying the Cantor diagonal argument to the enumerated list of all computable numbers, we produce a number not in it, but seems to be computable too, and that seems paradoxical.

For clarity, let me state the argument formally.
It suffices to consider the interval [0,1] only.
Consider $0 \leq a \leq 1$, and let it's decimal representation be found as
$$
a =\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-n} a^{(n)}
$$
We say that $a$ is computable, if there is a Turing machine $T_a$ which receives $n$ and outputs $a^{(n)}$ in finite time, i.e., it always halts.

Let $A$ be the set of all computable numbers.
A moment's reflection shows that $A$ is countably many.
For example, we can implement $T_a$ in (say) Python, always choosing the program with the shortest string length, and we sort $T_a$ by their program according to the ASCII characters' dictionary order.
If two programs, which both implement $T_a$, have the same string length, choose the one with foremost dictionary order.
This gives a sorting function of $A$.

Let $A$ be enumerated with $a_1, a_2, a_3 \dotsc$. Now, construct a number $b$ so that:
$$
b =\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-n} b^{(n)} \\
b^{(n)} =\begin{cases}
4,\quad a_n^{(n)} =3 \\
3,\quad \rm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
We see $b \notin A$.
Moreover, $b^{(n)}$ is obtained within finite time, since we only need to know $a_n^{(n)}$'s value.
Thus $b \in A$, but $b \neq a_n$ for all $n =1,2,3, \dotsc$, a contradiction.

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28393/why-does-cantors-diagonal-argument-yield-uncomputable-numbers) is related, but I don't think it's a duplicate.
The post applies the diagonal argument on the reals, rather than the computable numbers.

Comment: How is your Python program going to determine which Turing machines always halt?  (In fact, it can’t.)

Comment: Perhaps I am a bit ignorant but I fail to see how $a$ is a computable number from your definition.

Comment: @MitchellSpector The program listed to produce $a_n$'s are chosen to always halt, so I think the definition of $b$ doesn't need to worry about the halting problem of existing $a_n$'s.

Comment: @MatthewLiu I think this is the Wikipedia definition of [computable Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number). What part did I miss?

Comment: There is no way for a program to look at a Turing machine (or at a string that represents a Turing machine) and determine if it always halts.  Your contradiction essentially proves that.

Comment: My bad, misread your notation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> seems to be computable too

It's not, though. To run your argument you need to begin with a **computable** list of all the computable reals. But this doesn't exist.

We do of course have a computable list of all the *Turing machines*, but not every Turing machine describes a real number - to tell whether a Turing machine describes a real number, we need to know whether it *halts on every input*. But the set of (indices of) Turing machines which halt on all inputs is noncomputable (in fact, *very* noncomputable - strictly more complicated than the halting problem itself, which focuses on a *single specific* input!).

(Incidentally, the context of real numbers just adds a bit of unnecessary "noise" to the problem (and actually, this is true in Cantor's original argument as well); it's easier at first to just think about *infinite sequences of $0$s and $1$s*.)

---

Put another way:

> The computable reals are "computably uncountable."

Similarly, the polynomial-time computable reals are "polynomial-time uncountable" (but they are "computably countable"). Cantor's argument shows that the "simply describable reals" are never "simply describably countable," for any reasonable meaning of "simply describable;" the full result - *actual* uncountability of the *actual* reals - is what you get when you take "simply describable" to just mean "in existence."